# One liner for handling dictionary KeyError

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python and still learning the tricks.

How can i convert the following code to a single liner, is it possible in Python? There has to be a neat way of doing this.

```
try:
    image_file = self.request.files['image_path']
except:
    image_file = None
```

Comment: There isn't such a thing as a single-line-try in Python. If the exception you're guarding against is a `KeyError` from a `dict`, then you could use [`get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

Comment: what is self.request.files - is it a dictionary ?

Comment: BTW, using a naked `except` is generally not a good idea (unless it's at the end of a chain of named except clauses, and even then you probably want to re-raise the exception after printing a warning or performing some other processing). Always specify the exception(s) that you want to catch.

Comment: @PM2Ring thanks for the tip

Comment: @Tarptaeya i am using Tornado request handler

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a dictionary, use the [`dict.get()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to return a default value for missing keys:

```
image_file = self.request.files.get('image_path')
```

Also, do *not* use pokemon exception handling. You really don't need to catch them all here; if a key is missing, `KeyError` is raised, if you must use `try..except` should catch *just* that one exception with `except KeyError:`.

Comment: can you please elaborate, still in the phase of trying to wrap my head around python

Comment: I love the phrase "pokemon exception handling". :)

Comment: @Baig: I've linked to the appropriate documentation for dictionaries. You didn't tell us more about where `self.request` comes from, is this code from  a Tornado request handler perhaps?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes it is from Tornado request handler

Comment: @Baig: that's a standard Python dictionary, so any of the standard dictionary operations apply there.